# replace multiple connecting instances of <br /> with one single <br /> php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am stripping HTML and replacing all `<div>` and `<p>` tags with `<br />` tags. Problem is that I am left with random `<br />` tags like

```
<br /><br /><br />
<br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br />
```

I am taking the body of an email and stripping tags like

```
$comment = strip_tags($comment,'<div><p>');
$comment = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "", $comment);
$comment = str_replace("</p>", "<br />", $comment);
$comment = preg_replace("/<div[^>]*?>/", "", $comment);
$comment = str_replace("</div>", "<br />", $comment);
```

I want to be able to replace any instance of at least 2 `<br />` tags next to each other with one single `<br />` tag. At this point every `<br />` will match exactly as I have shown, but...there is a possibility that they can vary like `<br>`, `<br />` so just need to make sure that I can replace any type of br tag (when there are at least 2 of them) with one single one when they are sequentially repeated next to each other.

The "possibility" of a br tag looking like `<br>` is based on if it was already in the original HTML that I did not catch. I know I can do a `str_replace("<br>", "<br />", $comment)` but I was hoping to shorten my code and not add more lines.

Any idea how to do this? Im sure there is regex involved and `preg_replace` but not sure where to start.

Comment: First replace all `<br>` with `<br />`. Then you know what to do.

Comment: How is the HTML produced? Although regex for this is easy, but you know… “*Asking for HTML, JSON, etc. regexes tends to be met with negative reactions. If there is a parser for it, use that instead.*”

Comment: Please give a sample HTML and expected result sample

Comment: `$comment = preg_replace('~(?:\s*<br\h*/?>\s*){2,}~i', '<br />', $comment);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `$comment = strip_tags($comment, '<div><p>')`, there will be *no* `<br>` left as it is not an allowed tag. So the only `<br />` would be from your four replacements below. You only need to care about the form "`<br />`" in the other words. But handling *just* `<br />` vs. all other `<br>` form aren't much different in difficulty.

---

Anyway, you could use:

```
$comment = preg_replace('/(\s*<br[^>]*>){2,}/', '\1', $comment);
```

- `<br[^>]*>` — match any kind of `<br>` tag
- `\s*<br[^>]*>` — match zero or more whitespaces before the `<br>` tag
- `(\s*<br[^>]*>)` — group this regex and capture into `\1`
- `(…){2,}` — match two or more such groups.

The replacement will keep the *last* `<br>` found.